# JPQL query with count function on an association field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

As stated in the JPA 2.1 specification the count function can be applied to an association field in the select clause:

> [...] The path expression argument to COUNT may terminate in either a state field or **a association field**, or the argument to COUNT may be an identification variable. (JSR 338, section 4.8.5)

So I expect such a query to be valid JPQL:

```
SELECT count(i.courses) FROM Instructor i GROUP BY i
```

(instructor entity has bidirectional one-to-many relationship to course entity)

Jet if i try to execute the statement on Hibernate (4.3.11) as a JPA provider it fails (i.e. SQLGrammarException) but EcplipseLink can execute it. So is Hibernate not compliant or did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct JPQL way of getting the size of a collection field is to use

```
SELECT SIZE(i.courses) FROM Instructor i GROUP BY i
```

The JPQL you state is likely not portable, since the JPQL BNF says

```
aggregate_expression ::= { AVG | MAX | MIN | SUM } ([DISTINCT] state_field_path_expression) |
    COUNT ([DISTINCT] identification_variable | state_field_path_expression |
    single_valued_object_path_expression)
```

and it does not include collection_valued_path_expression expressions in that, so I would use the `SIZE` function myself

Comment: Very true, the arguement to count can be an association field, but must be single valued (one-to-one and many-to-one only).